# Cannot download iOS OTA from HTTPS Server, but from Dropbox

Tags: ios, ota

I have an HTTPS server and my iOS app is ready to be distributed. Signed it using Distribution provisioning profile and has created plist for it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://some-server-url/e-App.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://some-server-url/image.57x57.png</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://some-server-url/image.512x512.jpg</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.com.e-App</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>e-App</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have tried to deploy it to my server and have added MIME Types in IIS `application/xml` for `.plist` and `application/octet-stream` for `.ipa`

Unfortunately when I go to my `download.html` from iPad Safari, it pops up error of cannot download the app. While I put it in Dropbox for testing, it works perfectly (with some changes in URL in .html and .plist).

Anyone can suggest how to fix this? I have been looking solutions out there but none of them can bring me fortune.

This happens on all devices.

I don't have the logs now, but I remember it gives me this error:

```
MIInstaller performInstallationWithError
```

Anyway, the server prompts authentication that user need to input email and password. Maybe this is the cause?

Comment: Please check the device console for a more detailed error description and post it.

Comment: I can't remember the logs, but AFAI can remember, it has error of `MIInstaller performInstallationWithError`

Comment: It will be helpful to reproduce the error again as the full report may help us help you.

Comment: Is your ssl certificate valid?

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure the SSL cert is valid

Comment: can you post a link to the non working ota install?

Comment: Sorry can't because it only can be accessed by VPN